# MainWindow_Loaded isn't triggered on my WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently following the `Pluralsight C# Fundamentals: Part 1` and on the `Classes and Objects` section the video instructs me to create a new WPF Applicaiton in Visual Studio and fill in the code. This results in the following.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Employee e1 = new Employee("Ash");

            Employee e2 = new Employee("Lee");

            Output.Text = e1.Name + "" + e2.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Employee is basically a dummy class which has been defined with a single instance variable `Name` in order to demonstrate how constructors work.

There is also a `TextBlock` in my `MainWindow.xaml` called `Output` which I am trying to update on the last line of the code.

Initially I had the code contained in `MainWindow_Loaded` in the constructor `MainWindow`, the tutorial says this is bad practice and it should look like my first code snippet.

However this stops the application working. My question is what is the problem?

Is the tutorial outdated? Am I running the wrong version? Was it changed in Beta?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you subscribe to window's `Loaded` event...?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure the Loaded event mapped to MainWindow_Loaded in the XAML for MainWindow.

Edit: Moving my comment below into the answer, as it seems to be more helpful:

open up MainWindow.xaml (not MainWindow.xaml.cs), click on the window (make sure you don't have one of the controls selected), open the properties box (i believe F4 will do that), click on the events tab in the properties box, find Loaded and make sure that is mapped to MainWindow_Loaded (if it is blank you should be able to select your already existing one)

Comment: I'm new to C# and VS2010, could you step me through it?

Comment: open up MainWindow.xaml (not MainWindow.xaml.cs), click on the window (make sure you don't have one of the controls selected), open the properties box (i believe F4 will do that), click on the events tab in the properties box, find Loaded and make sure that is mapped to MainWindow_Loaded (if it is blank you should be able to select your already existing one).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Once I had the keywords I was able to find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.80).aspx with some google foo. Since there are several correct answers I'll select yours as the solution since you answered first.

Comment: That was it! I have no idea why it didn't keep my `Window_Loaded` when I first double-clicked in the text input for the Loaded event. When I double-clicked while it was empty, it made a new `Window_Loaded_1` method, so replacing the contents of the text box with `Window_Loaded` and then double-clicking to make sure it found it did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this programatically you can use:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're probably missing actual subscribtion to `Loaded` event, you can fix that in two ways:

XAML:

```
<Window ... Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
```

Code behind, eg. in constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an edge case. But one of you all may be as "creative" as me... If you have a constructor for the WPF class an accidentally omit the call to InitializeComponent() that will caused the Windows_Load event to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing Loaded="Window_Loaded" in my MainWindow.xaml. You'll probably see it on line 8 in the xaml below the designer view. I'm also using the Pluralsight program for many different things in WPF. The Dispatcher and the backgroundWorker are both essential on heavy loaded WPF apps, like with PLC's. The event based tasks and delegates for the UI is the same for the window. The Loaded is exactly like the on_click event, except fires on load.