# Microchip HID_PnP_Demo, WinForm to WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I've been trying to learn about WPF since I've been using VB.NET and WindowsForm for the past 10 years in a very few small projects.

I'm planning a simple interface to control my house with a PIC18F97J94.

Microchip provides an [example](http://www.mediafire.com/download/jb9x92bdrou7okm/vc%23_2005_express.rar) (That's part of the MLA solution, it's in C# and WinForm) which I could workaround and finish my project but I want to learn WPF and C#.

The problem I'm encountering is with the .Handle:

```
RegisterDeviceNotification(this.Handle, pDeviceBroadcastHeader, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
```

Error CS1061    'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Handle' and no extension method 'Handle' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found.

The full code block is the next one:

```
public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        ProgressBar1.ToolTip = ("If using a board/PIM without a potentiometer, apply an adjustable voltage to the I/O pin.");
        ANxVoltage_lbl.ToolTip = ("If using a board/PIM without a potentiometer, apply an adjustable voltage to the I/O pin.");
        ToggleLEDs_btn.ToolTip = ("Sends a packet of data to the USB device.");
        PushbuttonState_lbl.ToolTip = ("Try pressing pushbuttons on the USB demo board/PIM.");

        //Register for WM_DEVICECHANGE notifications.  This code uses these messages to detect plug and play connection/disconnection events for USB devices
        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE DeviceBroadcastHeader = new DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE();
        DeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
        DeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(DeviceBroadcastHeader);
        DeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_reserved = 0;    //Reserved says not to use...
        DeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_classguid = InterfaceClassGuid;

        //Need to get the address of the DeviceBroadcastHeader to call RegisterDeviceNotification(), but
        //can't use "&DeviceBroadcastHeader".  Instead, using a roundabout means to get the address by 
        //making a duplicate copy using Marshal.StructureToPtr().
        IntPtr pDeviceBroadcastHeader = IntPtr.Zero;  //Make a pointer.
        pDeviceBroadcastHeader = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(DeviceBroadcastHeader)); //allocate memory for a new DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE structure, and return the address 
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(DeviceBroadcastHeader, pDeviceBroadcastHeader, false);  //Copies the DeviceBroadcastHeader structure into the memory already allocated at DeviceBroadcastHeaderWithPointer
        RegisterDeviceNotification(this.Handle, pDeviceBroadcastHeader, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);


        //Now make an initial attempt to find the USB device, if it was already connected to the PC and enumerated prior to launching the application.
        //If it is connected and present, we should open read and write handles to the device so we can communicate with it later.
        //If it was not connected, we will have to wait until the user plugs the device in, and the WM_DEVICECHANGE callback function can process
        //the message and again search for the device.
        if (CheckIfPresentAndGetUSBDevicePath())    //Check and make sure at least one device with matching VID/PID is attached
        {
            uint ErrorStatusWrite;
            uint ErrorStatusRead;


            //We now have the proper device path, and we can finally open read and write handles to the device.
            WriteHandleToUSBDevice = CreateFile(DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            ErrorStatusWrite = (uint)Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            ReadHandleToUSBDevice = CreateFile(DevicePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            ErrorStatusRead = (uint)Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            if ((ErrorStatusWrite == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (ErrorStatusRead == ERROR_SUCCESS))
            {
                AttachedState = true;       //Let the rest of the PC application know the USB device is connected, and it is safe to read/write to it
                AttachedButBroken = false;
                StatusBox_txtbx.Text = "Device Found, AttachedState = TRUE";
            }
            else //for some reason the device was physically plugged in, but one or both of the read/write handles didn't open successfully...
            {
                AttachedState = false;      //Let the rest of this application known not to read/write to the device.
                AttachedButBroken = true;   //Flag so that next time a WM_DEVICECHANGE message occurs, can retry to re-open read/write pipes
                if (ErrorStatusWrite == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    WriteHandleToUSBDevice.Close();
                if (ErrorStatusRead == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    ReadHandleToUSBDevice.Close();
            }
        }
        else    //Device must not be connected (or not programmed with correct firmware)
        {
            AttachedState = false;
            AttachedButBroken = false;
        }

        if (AttachedState == true)
        {
            StatusBox_txtbx.Text = "Device Found, AttachedState = TRUE";
        }
        else
        {
            StatusBox_txtbx.Text = "Device not found, verify connect/correct firmware";
        }

        ReadWriteThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Added info:
The next code block is what I transferred from the WinForm example, however I get the warning CS0649 in the line:

```
internal char[] DevicePath;         //TCHAR array of any size
```

and

```
internal char[] dbcc_name;          //TCHAR array
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //-------------------------------------------------------BEGIN CUT AND PASTE BLOCK-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Constant definitions from setupapi.h, which we aren't allowed to include directly since this is C#
    internal const uint DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x02;
    internal const uint DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x10;
    //Constants for CreateFile() and other file I/O functions
    internal const short FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x80;
    internal const short INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;
    internal const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    internal const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    internal const uint CREATE_NEW = 1;
    internal const uint CREATE_ALWAYS = 2;
    internal const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    internal const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
    internal const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
    //Constant definitions for certain WM_DEVICECHANGE messages
    internal const uint WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
    internal const uint DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
    internal const uint DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = 0x8003;
    internal const uint DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;
    internal const uint DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = 0x0018;
    //Other constant definitions
    internal const uint DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x05;
    internal const uint DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE = 0x00;
    internal const uint ERROR_SUCCESS = 0x00;
    internal const uint ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 0x00000103;
    internal const uint SPDRP_HARDWAREID = 0x00000001;

    enum WM_DEVICECHANGE_ENUM : int//Public Enum WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer
    {
        DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED = 0x19,
        DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = 0x18,
        DBT_CUSTOMEVENT = 0x8006,
        DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000,
        DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = 0x8001,
        DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED = 0x8002,
        DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004,
        DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = 0x8003,
        DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC = 0x8005,
        DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = 0x7,
        DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG = 0x17,
        DBT_USERDEFINED = 0xFFFF
    }//End Enum


    //Various structure definitions for structures that this code will be using
    internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
    {
        internal uint cbSize;               //DWORD
        internal Guid InterfaceClassGuid;   //GUID
        internal uint Flags;                //DWORD
        internal uint Reserved;             //ULONG_PTR MSDN says ULONG_PTR is "typedef unsigned __int3264 ULONG_PTR;"  
    }

    internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
    {
        internal uint cbSize;               //DWORD
        internal char[] DevicePath;         //TCHAR array of any size
    }

    internal struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        internal uint cbSize;       //DWORD
        internal Guid ClassGuid;    //GUID
        internal uint DevInst;      //DWORD
        internal uint Reserved;     //ULONG_PTR  MSDN says ULONG_PTR is "typedef unsigned __int3264 ULONG_PTR;"  
    }

    internal struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
    {
        internal uint dbcc_size;            //DWORD
        internal uint dbcc_devicetype;      //DWORD
        internal uint dbcc_reserved;        //DWORD
        internal Guid dbcc_classguid;       //GUID
        internal char[] dbcc_name;          //TCHAR array
    }

    //DLL Imports.  Need these to access various C style unmanaged functions contained in their respective DLL files.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Returns a HDEVINFO type for a device information set.  We will need the 
    //HDEVINFO as in input parameter for calling many of the other SetupDixxx() functions.
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(
        ref Guid ClassGuid,     //LPGUID    Input: Need to supply the class GUID. 
        IntPtr Enumerator,      //PCTSTR    Input: Use NULL here, not important for our purposes
        IntPtr hwndParent,      //HWND      Input: Use NULL here, not important for our purposes
        uint Flags);            //DWORD     Input: Flags describing what kind of filtering to use.

    //Gives us "PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA" which contains the Interface specific GUID (different
    //from class GUID).  We need the interface GUID to get the device path.
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,           //Input: Give it the HDEVINFO we got from SetupDiGetClassDevs()
        IntPtr DeviceInfoData,          //Input (optional)
        ref Guid InterfaceClassGuid,    //Input 
        uint MemberIndex,               //Input: "Index" of the device you are interested in getting the path for.
        ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);    //Output: This function fills in an "SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA" structure.

    //SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList() frees up memory by destroying a DeviceInfoList
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet);          //Input: Give it a handle to a device info list to deallocate from RAM.

    //SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo() fills in an "SP_DEVINFO_DATA" structure, which we need for SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        uint MemberIndex,
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

    //SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty() gives us the hardware ID, which we use to check to see if it has matching VID/PID
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
        uint Property,
        ref uint PropertyRegDataType,
        IntPtr PropertyBuffer,
        uint PropertyBufferSize,
        ref uint RequiredSize);

    //SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() gives us a device path, which is needed before CreateFile() can be used.
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,                   //Input: Wants HDEVINFO which can be obtained from SetupDiGetClassDevs()
        ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData,                    //Input: Pointer to an structure which defines the device interface.  
        IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData,      //Output: Pointer to a SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA structure, which will receive the device path.
        uint DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize,     //Input: Number of bytes to retrieve.
        ref uint RequiredSize,                  //Output (optional): The number of bytes needed to hold the entire struct 
        IntPtr DeviceInfoData);                 //Output (optional): Pointer to a SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure

    //Overload for SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail().  Need this one since we can't pass NULL pointers directly in C#.
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,                   //Input: Wants HDEVINFO which can be obtained from SetupDiGetClassDevs()
        ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData,               //Input: Pointer to an structure which defines the device interface.  
        IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData,       //Output: Pointer to a SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA structure, which will contain the device path.
        uint DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize,     //Input: Number of bytes to retrieve.
        IntPtr RequiredSize,                    //Output (optional): Pointer to a DWORD to tell you the number of bytes needed to hold the entire struct 
        IntPtr DeviceInfoData);                 //Output (optional): Pointer to a SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure

    //Need this function for receiving all of the WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.  See MSDN documentation for
    //description of what this function does/how to use it. Note: name is remapped "RegisterDeviceNotificationUM" to
    //avoid possible build error conflicts.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(
        IntPtr hRecipient,
        IntPtr NotificationFilter,
        uint Flags);

    //Takes in a device path and opens a handle to the device.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string lpFileName,
        uint dwDesiredAccess,
        uint dwShareMode,
        IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
        uint dwCreationDisposition,
        uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    //Uses a handle (created with CreateFile()), and lets us write USB data to the device.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool WriteFile(
        SafeFileHandle hFile,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
        ref uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    //Uses a handle (created with CreateFile()), and lets us read USB data from the device.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool ReadFile(
        SafeFileHandle hFile,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToRead,
        ref uint lpNumberOfBytesRead,
        IntPtr lpOverlapped);



    //--------------- Global Varibles Section ------------------
    //USB related variables that need to have wide scope.
    bool AttachedState = false;                     //Need to keep track of the USB device attachment status for proper plug and play operation.
    bool AttachedButBroken = false;
    SafeFileHandle WriteHandleToUSBDevice = null;
    SafeFileHandle ReadHandleToUSBDevice = null;
    String DevicePath = null;   //Need the find the proper device path before you can open file handles.


    //Variables used by the application/form updates.
    bool PushbuttonPressed = false;     //Updated by ReadWriteThread, read by FormUpdateTimer tick handler (needs to be atomic)
    bool ToggleLEDsPending = false;     //Updated by ToggleLED(s) button click event handler, used by ReadWriteThread (needs to be atomic)
    uint ADCValue = 0;          //Updated by ReadWriteThread, read by FormUpdateTimer tick handler (needs to be atomic)
    uint ADCDiff = 0;
    //Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) for HID class devices.  Windows uses GUIDs to identify things.
    Guid InterfaceClassGuid = new Guid(0x4d1e55b2, 0xf16f, 0x11cf, 0x88, 0xcb, 0x00, 0x11, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30);
    //--------------- End of Global Varibles ------------------

    //-------------------------------------------------------END CUT AND PASTE BLOCK-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    WindowInteropHelper interopHelper;
    private BackgroundWorker ReadWriteThread = new BackgroundWorker();
    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    private Int32 BytesControl = 0;//Convert.ToInt32("000000000000000000000001", 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this.Handle with the following:

```
new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow).Handle
```

[WindowInteropHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper(v=vs.110).aspx) class is in the System.Windows.Interop namespace. And myWindow is the name of your Window.

Comment: Partially answered: yes. Now I'm getting a CS0649 warning and the software detects the hardware if it has been previously plugged and it doesn't detects it when it has been plugged or unplugged after running it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The Window_Loaded event wasn't related to the function:

Here's my fix:

[MainWindow_Loaded isn't triggered on my WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108507/mainwindow-loaded-isnt-triggered-on-my-wpf-application)